Prove that $\det(A)=\frac{1}{3!}\varepsilon_{IJK}\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{Ii}A_{Jj}A_{Kk}?$
How do I prove for the matrix $A=(A_{ij}) \implies$ $\det(A)=\frac{1}{3!}\varepsilon_{IJK}\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{Ii}A_{Jj}A_{Kk}?$
where $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol.
My attempt:
I could successfully prove $\det(A)=\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{1i}A_{2j}A_{3k}$
I know $\varepsilon_{IJK}=\begin{cases} 
      1 & (I,J,K) \text{ is an even permutatiions} \\
      -1& (I,J,K) \text{ is an odd permutatiions} \\
      0 & \text{ otherwise}
   \end{cases}$
Could you help me to prove?

You already proved that
$$\det(A)=\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{1i}A_{2j}A_{3k}.$$
The right hand side is
$$\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{Ii}A_{Jj}A_{Kk}$$
for the particular choice of $I=1; J=2; K=3$. Note that this object is completely antisymmetric in the indices $I,J,K$, so it must be a multiple of $\epsilon_{IJK}$ (why?), i.e. there is a scalar $D$ such that
$$\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{Ii}A_{Jj}A_{Kk} = \epsilon_{IJK}D.$$
Question: what is this scalar $D$? Once you answer these questions, you can solve for $D$ contracting both sides with $\epsilon^{IJK}$. Can you continue?
This argument is taken from

 this lecture by Pavel Grinfeld.

but do not watch it until you tried yourself!

Explicitly expand $\varepsilon_{IJK}\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{Ii}A_{Jj}A_{Kk}$ into a sum over $I,J$ and $K$. After some index renaming in each non-zero term, see that what you have is $6\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{1i}A_{2j}A_{3k}$.

there exists 6 non zero terms. They are $\varepsilon_{123}\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{1i}A_{2j}A_{3k}+\varepsilon_{231}\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{2i}A_{3j}A_{1k}+\varepsilon_{312}\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{3i}A_{1j}A_{2k}+\varepsilon_{132}\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{1i}A_{3j}A_{2k}+\varepsilon_{213}\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{2i}A_{1j}A_{3k}+\varepsilon_{321}\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{3i}A_{2j}A_{1k}$

These are the nonzero terms in the summation. Right?

Yes.  Now show that they are all equal.
